# 403 Authorization_RequestDenied when trying to read users

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, permission-denied

I'm trying to get a list of all users in the Exchange directory by using the API endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/
This works using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I get a preview with a list of 100 valid results.

However when accessing the same endpoint from my Python app, logging in with the same user, I'm getting the following response:

```
{'error': {'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied', 'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', 'innerError': {'request-id': '6924dba1-83ee-4865-9dcf-76b6cafcb808', 'date': '2019-07-04T21:08:28'}}}
```

This is the Python code I'm using, most of it is copied from the [python-sample-console-app](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app/)

```py
CLIENT_ID = '765bdd8d-b33d-489b-a039-3cdf41223aa4'

AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'
RESOURCE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
API_VERSION = 'v1.0'

import base64
import mimetypes
import os
import urllib
import webbrowser

from adal import AuthenticationContext
import pyperclip
import requests

def device_flow_session(client_id, auto=False):
    """Obtain an access token from Azure AD (via device flow) and create
    a Requests session instance ready to make authenticated calls to
    Microsoft Graph.
    client_id = Application ID for registered "Azure AD only" V1-endpoint app
    auto      = whether to copy device code to clipboard and auto-launch browser
    Returns Requests session object if user signed in successfully. The session
    includes the access token in an Authorization header.
    User identity must be an organizational account (ADAL does not support MSAs).
    """
    ctx = AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL, api_version=None)
    device_code = ctx.acquire_user_code(RESOURCE, client_id)

    # display user instructions
    if auto:
        pyperclip.copy(device_code['user_code']) # copy user code to clipboard
        webbrowser.open(device_code['verification_url']) # open browser
        print(f'The code {device_code["user_code"]} has been copied to your clipboard, '
              f'and your web browser is opening {device_code["verification_url"]}. '
              'Paste the code to sign in.')
    else:
        print(device_code['message'])

    token_response = ctx.acquire_token_with_device_code(RESOURCE,
                                                        device_code,
                                                        client_id)
    if not token_response.get('accessToken', None):
        return None

    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'Bearer {token_response["accessToken"]}',
                            'SdkVersion': 'sample-python-adal',
                            'x-client-SKU': 'sample-python-adal'})
    return session

def api_endpoint(url):
    """Convert a relative path such as /me/photo/$value to a full URI based
    on the current RESOURCE and API_VERSION settings in config.py.
    """
    if urllib.parse.urlparse(url).scheme in ['http', 'https']:
        return url # url is already complete
    return urllib.parse.urljoin(f'{RESOURCE}/{API_VERSION}/',
url.lstrip('/'))

session = device_flow_session(CLIENT_ID, True)
users = session.get(api_endpoint('users'))
print(users.json())
```

I also have the following permissions set in the Microsoft Azure portal:
[image: permissions]

Specifically `User.ReadBasic.All` should be sufficient to get a list of all users with just the basic properties like name and e-mail, but it still does not work.

Apparently, the issue was missing "user consent". Some weirdness is going on here, because theoretically the login page should ask for user consent automatically for all configured API permissions. After some more tinkering, I've found the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

- Register a new application on portal.azure.com
- Add the required config and API permissions beforehand
- When you change the required API permissions, the user **does not get asked again**
- Re-create the application on portal.azure.com any time you need to access a new API and change the application ID in your app accordingly

**Solution 2**

- Detect an 'Authorization_RequestDenied' error
- In case this happens, open a browser window with a special login URL for asking user consent
- Ask the user to restart the app after they have logged in successfully and given consent
- Here is the relevant code

```py
CONSENT_URL = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&state=12345&prompt=consent'
#...
response = session.get(api_endpoint('users')).json()
if 'error' in response and response['error']['code'] == 'Authorization_RequestDenied':
    print("Access denied. Consent page has been opened in the webbrowser. Please give user consent, then start the script again!")
    webbrowser.open(CONSENT_URL)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the solution. I tried creating a new application on the azure portal and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first use the graph explorer, you must have been asked for consent to use the explorer.

So when you login with the application you registered in azure portal, you also must have been asked for consent to use the application. But if you add/update the permissions after the consent. You must consent again.

[image]

You can force user consent through a url request, append &prompt=consent to the authentication request URL.

Or you just grant consent on behalf of all users in this directory. Granting admin consent for all users means that end users will not be shown a consent screen when using the application.

[image]

Comment: Admin consent is not required for these permissions. Also, it works in the graph explorer, without having any admin consent.

Comment: @simon574 You are right, but this is something different from graph explorer. See the updated answer.

Comment: I'm not sure where to add &prompt=consent in my code, there is no "authentication request url". I didn't find anything in the ADAL docs about asking consent. This is not a webapp, it's a native python app. I cannot grant admin consent because this is an organizational account and I'm not admin in that organization.

Comment: @simon574 Here is the consent document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent And here is the request document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent

Comment: @simon574 You can send a request in the browse like this 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize? client_id={your_client_id} &response_type=code&response_mode=query &resource=https://graph.microsoft.com &state=12345 &prompt=consent

Comment: I've managed to build a working consent request, had to include https:// in the resource=url, here is my code: ```CLIENT_ID = '...'
CONSENT_URL = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&state=12345&prompt=consent'
```
I only needed to open this URL once and click accept, after that the app works as expected!

Comment: However, if I add &prompt=consent to the URL I use for the device login, it doesn't prompt the user for consent. I find this very confusing. Is there a way to test if the user has already given consent, other than checking for "access denied" error codes?